# How to get the 2 greatest values between multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to figure out how to get the 2 highest values from 5 fields. I know about the `greatest` function, but I don't know how to pull out the second highest value, too.

Basically, the table has 5 `NUMBER` type fields. In this example, the last two columns are my desired results.

```
| Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 | Score5 | | Highest1_value | Highest2_value 
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ +----------------+---------------
|    10  |    20  |    30  |    40  |   50   | |       50       |       40
|    20  |    20  |    12  |    17  |    0   | |       20       |       20
|     7  |     7  |     7  |     7  |   11.1 | |       11.1     |        7
|    10  |    10  |    10  |    10  |   10   | |       10       |       10
```

Comment: do you have an identifier for each row?

Comment: In your second row highest2_value should be 17 I guess.. Am I right?

Comment: vkp, Yes, I have unique id. Teja, No, Score1 and  Score2 both have 20, so they are highest numbers

Comment: how should the expected output look like? please post it as formatted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpivot the data and use `row_number` to get the first 2 highest scores per id.

```
select id
,max(case when rnum=1 then val end) as highest_1
,max(case when rnum=2 then val end) as highest_2
from (select id,score,val,row_number() over(partition by id order by val desc) as rnum
      from (select * from t --replace this with your tablename
            unpivot (val for score in (score1,score2,score3,score4,score5)) p
          ) tbl
      ) tbl
group by id
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do without unpivot in other databases? May be in mysql?

Comment: you can get `max` or `min` with `greatest` or `least` directly without unpivoting (in MySQL). Because the OP needs 2 max values, i couldn't think of a way without using `row_number`.

Comment: This returns values only from Score4  and  Score5 fields ?

Comment: ordering had to be on `val` field instead of `score` in `row_number`. i changed it and should work as expected now.

Comment: Now works, I accept this answer as this was first one. thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

If I correct understand, you need this:

```
select your_table.*, REGEXP_SUBSTR(h.str, '^[^\-]+') AS h1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(h.str, '[^\-]+$') AS h2  FROM your_table
inner join  (
    select id, listagg(sc, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sc DESC) str FROM(
        select id, sc, row_number() over(partition by id order by sc desc) rn from (
            select id, sc FROM your_table
            UNPIVOT (sc for col in (Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5))
        ) tt
    )ttt
    where rn <= 2
    GROUP BY id
) h
ON your_table.id =  h.id
```

Comment: regex for this problem is an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: @vkp - Of course there is possible to do same with instr and substring, just regex was fastet thing appeared in my head

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids unpivot, just lots of cut&paste&modify:

```
SELECT 
   dt.*,
   CASE maxscore -- GREATEST on all but the highest value,
                 -- simplified to a "Valued Case" based on mathguy's comment
      WHEN score1 THEN Greatest(score2, score3, score4, score5)
      WHEN score2 THEN Greatest(score1, score3, score4, score5)
      WHEN score3 THEN Greatest(score1, score2, score4, score5)
      WHEN score4 THEN Greatest(score1, score2, score3, score5)
      ELSE Greatest(score1, score2, score3, score4)
   END
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*,
      Greatest(Score1,Score2,Score3,Score4,Score5) AS maxscore
   FROM tab t
 ) dt
```

Based on @vkp's & @mathguy's comments without Derived Table/Inline View:

```
SELECT 
   t.*,
   Greatest(Score1,Score2,Score3,Score4,Score5) as Highest1_value,
   CASE Greatest(Score1,Score2,Score3,Score4,Score5)-- GREATEST on all but the highest value
      WHEN score1 THEN Greatest(       score2,score3,score4,score5)
      WHEN score2 THEN Greatest(score1,       score3,score4,score5)
      WHEN score3 THEN Greatest(score1,score2,       score4,score5)
      WHEN score4 THEN Greatest(score1,score2,score3,       score5)
      ELSE             Greatest(       score1,score2,score3,score4)
   END as Highest2_value
FROM tab t
```

Comment: why a `maxscore` calculation at all? you could've included it in the `case` expression itself.

Comment: This can be simplified further. Write the `case` expression like this: `case greatest(score1,...,score5) when score1 then ... when score2 then...` (make it into a "simple" case expression as opposed to a "searched" case expression; you will not need to repeat the outer `greatest(...)`, as it will be on the "left-hand side").